# Identification of padding scheme in RSA

Tags: encryption, language-agnostic, rsa

How to determine the padding scheme used in a **RSA** encrypted message?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to perform PKCS#1 v1.5 or OAEP decryption and see if you hit gold. The unpadding will fail if the wrong algorithm is chosen.

It is possible to raw decipher and then look at the resulting scheme by representing the padded message as hexadecimals. If the resulting octet string (byte array) starts with `0002` then it's likely PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. If it starts with `00` and then a random looking byte it's probably OAEP. As you can see, this is just a heuristic, not a full fledged algorithm. Note that OAEP's MFG1 can be parameterized with a hash function, but usually SHA-1 is used.

RSA-KEM is not used much, but as it results in a completely random key seed (possibly excluding the first bit), there is no way to test for RSA-KEM other than to expect RSA-KEM if the ciphertext and private key can be verified to be correct and the value doesn't match one of the other schemes / lacks structure.

---

**The protocol should define which algorithm is used. Leaving the choice of algorithm to the decryption routine opens up your implementation to attacks. The security proof of ciphers doesn't allow for other algorithms to be chosen.**

So you can use above to analyze the protocol, but please do not use it in your implementation to choose between algorithms in the field.